# How do I make it so each box does not overlap the one to its right?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

fyi - react css is pretty similar to regular css

each individual box code

```
  export const CardWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.backgrounds.project};
  padding-bottom: 28px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 375px;
`;
```

each box should look like this
[image]

but when i increase the width, in this img below, there should be black lines to seperate each box
[image]

```
  export const DeploymentsWrapper = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 335px);
  grid-gap: 20px 30px;
  max-height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 13px 30px 30px 30px;
`;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `max-width` for your cards to `100%`

Comment: yes! this worked, however, i have one last issue, how do i make the box bigger so the text does not overlap the box? 

https://imgur.com/a/0no6mMg

Comment: Two options.. either set ```overflow:scroll``` for your card or set ```word-break:break-all``` on element which keep this text inside.